# No response for RPC requests from opendaylight testtool simulator devices

Tags: rpc, simulator, opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf

I was able to simulate netconf devices with opendaylight simulators. During startup, I provided the yang schemas path too.

But, when I login to the device through netconf and send any RPC request applicable for the yang schemas, there is no response from the device.

Though the simulator device throws error if there is any syntax errors in my rpc requests, it is not responding with any data.

It is mentioned in the opendaylight github page that, for "set" requests, there will be OK response by default, but I dont see any response for any request.

Also, I do not see any error log in the simulator running bash session.

Any ideas on what is going wrong?